# Issue Installing Polymer on Arch Linux via npm

Tags: npm, polymer, polymer-2.x

I get the following error when installing Polymer CLI as follows

```
sudo npm install -g polymer-cli


29577 info lifecycle wd@1.5.0~install: wd@1.5.0
29578 verbose lifecycle wd@1.5.0~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle false
29579 verbose lifecycle wd@1.5.0~install: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/loc\
al/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
29580 verbose lifecycle wd@1.5.0~install: CWD: /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd
29581 silly lifecycle wd@1.5.0~install: Args: [ '-c', 'node scripts/build-browser-scripts' ]
29582 silly lifecycle wd@1.5.0~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
29583 info lifecycle wd@1.5.0~install: Failed to exec install script
29584 verbose unlock done using /root/.npm/_locks/staging-a072192f34a17023.lock for /usr/lib/node_modules/.staging
29585 verbose stack Error: wd@1.5.0 install: `node scripts/build-browser-scripts`
29585 verbose stack Exit status 1
29585 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
29585 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:160:13)
29585 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
29585 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
29585 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
29585 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
29586 verbose pkgid wd@1.5.0
```

Any idea how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I updated the `npm` and `bower` to the latest versions and then ran the install command again for `polymer-cli`. Now I get the following error message - it's a permissioning problem when running the script. I am not sure if this is down to the npm install script or if it is an arch linux problem.

```
sudo npm install -g polymer-cli

npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update! 
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN deprecated github@7.3.2: 'github' has been renamed to '@octokit/rest' (https://git.io/vNB11)
npm WARN deprecated @types/assert@0.0.29: See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12826
/usr/bin/polymer -> /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/bin/polymer.js

> uws@0.14.5 install /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/uws
> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0

sh: build_log.txt: Permission denied

> wd@1.5.0 install /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd
> node scripts/build-browser-scripts

/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
                    throw err0;
                    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd/build'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:905:18)
    at sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd/scripts/build-browser-scripts.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wd@1.5.0 install: `node scripts/build-browser-scripts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the wd@1.5.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-01-28T19_51_38_197Z-debug.log
```

The issue now is when the script tries to make this directory:

```
mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd/build'
```

Answer (score 3):

1. use `--unsafe-perm` option to install polymer-cli globally as described [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/836)

`sudo npm install -g polymer-cli --unsafe-perm`

2. or [Change npm's Default Directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-two-change-npms-default-directory)

and then install `npm install -g polymer-cli` without sudo and `--unsafe-perm` option.

Answer (score 1):

Switched to Yarn and it installs!

```
sudo yarn global add polymer-cli

yarn global v1.3.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning polymer-cli > babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update! 
warning polymer-cli > bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
warning polymer-cli > github@7.3.2: 'github' has been renamed to '@octokit/rest' (https://git.io/vNB11)
warning polymer-cli > polyserve > @types/assert@0.0.29: See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12826
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "polymer-cli@1.5.7" with binaries:
      - polymer
Done in 61.35s.
```